Using the Borel-Cantelli-Lemma to show that numbers 0,...,b-1 appear almost surely infinitely often in the b-adic representation of a real number
following problem:
let $U \sim unif([0,1])$ be a uniformly distributed random variable on the unit intervall $[0,1]$.
The $b$-adic representation of $U$ is then given as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} D_n \cdot b^{-n}$ where $b \in \mathbb{N}$ , $b \geq 2$ and $D_n$ in turn is a discretely uniformly distributed random variable on $\{0, \dots, b-1 \}$.
Now, show that almost surely every digit $0,\dots , b-1$ appears infinitely often in $U$, that is:
$\mathbb{P}(\{ \# \{n\geq 1 \ : \ D_n = j \}=\infty \ : \ \forall j=0,\dots,b-1\}=1$
my question:
I first only want to get to the point of beeing able to formalize the problem so far that I am able to use the Borel-Cantelli-Lemma and not completely solving the problem.
That means, defining a useful sequence of events in the sigma-Algebra of a probability space that makes sense and the rest I would like to do on my own (showing the divergence etc.)
my idea:
I define a discrete probability space as the image space of every single of these $D_n$ as:
$(\Omega_n = \{0,\dots,b-1\} \  , \ \mathcal{A}=\mathcal{P}(\{0,\dots,b-1\}) \ , \ \mathbb{P_n})$
where $\mathcal{A}$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra and $\mathcal{P}(\cdot)$ the power set.
I have the knowledge that $\mathbb{P_n}(\{D_n=j\})=\frac{1}{b}$
now I also know that all the $(D_n)_n$ are stochastically independent and I need to "merge" all of these single probability spaces together in only one probability space so that I can talk about the whole thing:
$\Omega := \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \times \dots = \{ \ \omega=(\omega_1 , \omega_2 , \dots) : \omega_i \in \Omega_i \ , \forall i=1,2,\dots \} $
$\mathbb{P}(\{(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots)\}) := \Pi_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P_n}(\{\omega_i\})$
I call the event I am concerned with: $A_n :=\{D_n = j \}$ for $j \in \{0,\dots,b-1\}$
with $\pi_i:\Omega \rightarrow \Omega_i$ beeing the projection on the $i$-th component I can write:
$\pi^{-1}(A_n) = \Omega_1 \times \Omega_2 \dots \Omega_{n-1} \times A_n \dots \times \Omega_{n+1} \times \dots $
and as probability I get
$ \mathbb{P}(\pi^{-1}(A_n)) = \mathbb{P}_1(\Omega_1) \cdot \mathbb{P}_2(\Omega_2) \cdot \dots \cdot \mathbb{P}_{n-1}(\Omega_{n-1}) \cdot \mathbb{P}(A_n) \cdot \mathbb{P}_{n+1}(\Omega_{n+1}) \cdot \dots = \frac{1}{b} $
then I can finally define my sequence of events in the product-sigma-algebra as:
$(A_k)_k = (\{D_k = j\})_k \mathcal{A}$
and then the limes superior is
$\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty } A_n = \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{k=n}^{\infty} A_k $
is this correct?

Hi! Since your post is somewhat long, you may get better response if you drill in on a part that you're not sure about and ask specifically about that. If you want to ask about the overall approach, try to summarize it in a short paragraph near the top (but a bit more than just "I want to go by way of Borel-Cantelli") and then clearly indicate that the more detailed material is there more as context.

Hi, thank you for the hint. Luckily, Wei answered to it, but I will stick to the advice in future posts.

This looks fine in general, one small detail is in your definition of the product probability measure:
$$\mathbb{P}(\{(\omega_1,\omega_2,\dots)\}) := \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P_n}(\{\omega_i\})$$
This isn't the correct definition, indeed the infinite product on the RHS is always zero in your case because every $\mathbb{P_n}(\{\omega_i\}) = \frac1b$.
The rigorous definition is that $\mathbb P$ is the probability measure on the product $\sigma$-algebra such that if $B_n\in \mathcal A$ for each $n$ then
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\prod_{n=1}^\infty B_n\right) := \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P_n}(B_n)$$
But usually we would skip all of this formality of defining the exact probability space we're working in, and just define $A_n = \{ D_n=j \}$.

Thank you very much for taking the time reading my quite long question. I appreciate it and it helped me very much.
